# Add a variable using PHP to a css file

Tags: php, css

I have a page for movie online reservation where user can reserve any seat in any show, but I have a problem that the clear, reserve button are fixed and I need to make them move under the last row of the seats.
I used a variable called $top to order rows...and now I need to make the css dynamic

This is my css for the clear, reserve button

```
#holder{
 height:<?php echo $top; ?>px;   //here's the problem, it doesnt work for me
 width:550px;
 background-color:white;
 border:0px solid #A4A4A4;
 margin-left:10px;
}
```

This is the php code to get $top

```
<?php

$cols = 0;
$rows = 0;

$user_reserved_seats = array();

foreach( $seats as $seat )
{
$class = 'seat';

$seat_code = $seat['seats_code'];
$row = substr( $seat_code, 0, 1 ); //?

if( $row != $previous_row && $previous_row )
{
    ++$rows;
    $cols = 0;
}

$top = 35 * $rows;
$left = 35 * $cols;

if( $seat['reserved'] )
{
    $classToAdd = 'selectedSeat';

    if( $_GET['edit'] && $seat['member_id'] == $_SESSION['member_id'] )
    {
        $user_reserved_seats[] = $seat['seats_id'];

        $classToAdd = 'selectingSeat';
    }

    $class .= ' ' . $classToAdd;

}

echo "<li id=\"{$seat['seats_id']}\" class=\"{$class}\" style=\"top: {$top}px;left:{$left}px\">
        <a title=\"{$seat_code}\">{$seat_code}</a>
    </li>";

$previous_row = substr( $seat_code, 0, 1 ); //??
++$cols;
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: php can only run in a `.php` file, and not in `.css` If you want to create dynamic stylesheet, just write your css inside a `.php` file enclosed with `<style> </style>`

Comment: You haven't provided enough code. Where's the PHP that generates $top?

Comment: @PHPfan, it is a .php file

Comment: @ouzoumzak then please stop people from having to guess by posting enough code for someone to answer the question.

Comment: @popnoodles my bad, I;m sry

Comment: @ouzoumzak, if it's a php file, then what doesn't work?

Comment: as PHP fan said - make your css file a php file instead, put everything in echoes and style src="style.php"

Comment: argh! Where does that CSS get outputted? Can you post the PHP that creates $top AND that outputs that CSS in the order that it's executed in PHP?

Comment: I believe there's some confusion here. I think that ouzoumzak says that it's a php-file "creating the value of $top" that OP wants to have included into css-file, AND NOT php-file that creates the actual css. @ouzoumzak - Am I right?

Comment: true!! 
the file is a big .php file with some css code...I'm sure the $top variable is the right variable to choose...so I need to get the value of the $top to know where to put the reserve/cleat button

Comment: in addition, 
 $top = 35 * $rows;
so its obvious that $top shows how many px the seats are far from the top page

Comment: This may help you http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this (without using inline css) would be to create a seperate php file containing your css.

use a file named `style.php` (or anything else, as long as it ends with .php) containing:

```
<?php 
  header("Content-type: text/css");
  $top = '100'; 
?> 
height: <?php echo $top; ?>px;
width: 550px;
background-color: white;
border: 0px solid #A4A4A4;
margin-left: 10px;
```

include this file with:

```
<link href="style.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Actually your `$top` value is `100px;` so either remove `px` from var value or from height property :)

Comment: Whoops, sorry small typo :)